# Correct SQL syntax to check for the existance of a null value in an update procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table containing information about a contact's account balance. It contains columns to keep track of the date of the first invoice they ever had and the date of the last invoice they had as well as their current balance.

As each new invoice is created, it is intended that this table be updated via a simple stored procedure along the lines of:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateContactFinancialInformation
   @ContactId int,
   @InvoiceDate date,
   @Amount money
AS
   UPDATE Contacts.ContactsFinancialInformation
   SET LastInvoiceDate = @InvoiceDate,
       CurrentBalance = CurrentBalance + @Amount
   WHERE ContactId = @ContactId
```

When a new contact is created a default entry is created for them in the `ContactsFinancialInformation` table and the `FirstInvoiceDate` column will have a default value of `NULL`.

I would like to add a check for that in the basic SQL statement above so that if the `FirstInvoiceDate` column is NULL it too is set the the parameter `@InvoiceDate` that is being passed into the stored procedure.

What would be the most efficient way to do this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE Contacts.ContactsFinancialInformation

SET LastInvoiceDate = @InvoiceDate,
    FirstInvoiceDate = CASE WHEN FirstInvoiceDate IS NULL THEN @InvoiceDate ELSE FirstInvoiceDate END,

CurrentBalance = CurrentBalance + @Amount

WHERE ContactId = @ContactId
```

IMO, the only advantage of this solution vs COALESCE is a bit more code readability though.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like

FirstInvoiceDate = COALESCE(FirstInvoiceDate, InvoiceDate)

coalesce returns the first value which isn't null, so it will update with the identical value it already was if it is not null

Edit: 
i don't exactly know which SQL you have, it's not always coalesce

DB2, Ms SQL: COALESCE

MySQL: IFNULL

Oracle: nvl

just replace the COALESCE in the line I wrote with the correct expression of the sql you're using

Comment: Thank you I hadn't even consider coalesce in this context.